# JQuery navigation open/close navigation

Tags: jquery, animation, triggers, navigation

I have this Jquery code that triggers an animation-navigation by clicking the div #showMenu. But I cant get it to "close it again". Any help would be appriciated.

```
function init() {
    var showmenu = document.getElementById( 'showMenu' ),
        perspectiveWrapper = document.getElementById( 'perspective' ),
        container = perspectiveWrapper.querySelector( '.container' ),
        contentWrapper = container.querySelector( '.wrapper' );

    showMenu.addEventListener( clickevent, function( ev ) {
        ev.stopPropagation();
        ev.preventDefault();
        docscroll = scrollY();
        // change top of contentWrapper
        contentWrapper.style.top = docscroll * -1 + 'px';
        // mac chrome issue:
        document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        // add modalview class
        classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'modalview' );
        // animate..
        setTimeout( function() { classie.add( perspectiveWrapper, 'animate' ); }, 25 );
    });
```

Best regards
Jesper Andersen

Comment: you want to close div sudden or animated ?

Comment: I'm close to say that it dosen't matter, but it would be nice if it was closing animated.